# Seeking Advice: Improving Google Indexing for Company Search Website

Tags: google-search

We're currently facing a challenge with our company search website (companies.creditreports.dk/en) tailored for the Danish market, and I'm seeking advice for this.

The website's company pages are mass-generated automatically and they include information about them such as financial statements, key ratios, graphs etc. There is also some automatically generated texts based on the data from the company's financials.

Issue Summary:

Initial Setup:

As of early September, our website featured over 1,000 distinct company pages, all of which were submitted to Google for indexing. Initially, about half of these pages were promptly indexed.
October Update: By the 31st of October, 44% of our pages were indexed.
Expansion & Current Challenge: In an effort to expand our offerings, we added 10,000 more companies to our site. These new pages were submitted to Google for indexing on November 1st. However, more than a month has passed, and Google has not indexed these new additions. This has resulted in the indexed page percentage dropping to approximately 4%, according to the Google Search Console. Moreover, the total number of indexed pages has decreased slightly.

Technical Details:

We utilize a sitemap for our website.
Our website does not have a robots.txt file.

Question:

Are there specific methods or strategies we can employ to enhance the visibility of our mass-generated company search pages, ensuring they are indexed by Google? Any insights, experiences, or suggestions on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!